# Dynamic html table with django

Tags: python, django

I want to realize HTML page with table which consist from date from database. And if I add element to database I want to HTML table updated too. How to realize it with django?

Comment: Share your existing code you have written

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

In your **models.py** file :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    foo = models.CharField(max_length=...)
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=...)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.foo, self.bar
```

Then, in your **views.py** file:

```
def MyFunction(request):

    my_var = MyModel.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'Template.html', {"my_var": my_var})
```

And finally in your **template.html** file :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% for object in my_var_list %}

<table style="width:90%">
    <tbody>
        <p></p>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>{{ object.foo }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>{{ object.bar }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Next time, read StackOverflow documentations, and what you have done before to post your question.

Comment: Cycle "for" is not working. I don't know why. I added "endfor" after </table> but it whatever does not working

Comment: I forgot endfor. I will add it in few minutes