# Does not work cycle "for"

Tags: python, django

I have a *models.py*:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    Party_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Film = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

*viesws.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from description.models import Part

class PartyNumView(ListView):
    template_name = 'part_list.html'
    model = Part

    def partList(self, request):
        my_var = Part.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'part_list.html', {"my_var": my_var})
```

And HTML template *part_list.html*:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block activeButton %}
    <li class="active"><a href="/parties">Описание партий</a></li>
    <li><a href="/measures">Ic и QE</a></li>
{% endblock %}

{% block tableName %}
    Список партий
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for object in my_var %}
        {{object.Party_number}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content%}
```

My question is why part of code which consist cycle "for" does not working? i.e. objects of Party_number does not displayed on html page

**UPDATE**
I change *object.Party_number* to *{{object.Party_number}}*, but whatever it does not working

Comment: Are there any `Part` objects? You should also use `{{ object.Party_number }}` (with curly braces).

Comment: It seems you are using strange combination of Class views and function views. Where method partList should be called?

Comment: Because he's copying my answer in order to set his question (with his previous bad SO question) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641033/dynamic-html-table-with-django/50641183?noredirect=1#comment88294291_50641183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a custom method, `partList`, but it is not being called from anywhere. The method is pointless and you should delete it.

If you want to add data to the template context in a class-based view, you need to define `get_context_data`. However there is no reason to do that here as it would just do what ListView does for you anyway. You should use the variable that the view automatically populates, which is `object_list`.

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{ object.Party_number }}
{% endfor %}
```